# How do I update a Scala/Swing programmatically from an external class?

Tags: java, swing, scala, scala-swing

For example the following code shows a simple table

```
import java.awt.Dimension
import swing._

object SunsetTable extends SimpleSwingApplication {

  var model = Array(List("BHP", 1).toArray)

  lazy val ui = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
    val table = new Table(model, Array("Security", "Price")) {
      preferredViewportSize = new Dimension(1200, 600)
    }
    contents += new ScrollPane(table)
  }

  def top = new MainFrame {
    contents = ui
  }

}
```

Suppose I have an external class

```
class Counter {
    for (i <- 1 to 10) {
        // update SunsetTable with i
        Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
}
```

How would I update SunsetTable "Price" column with the counter i?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `lazy val ui = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) { ... }` you're making a new anonymous extension to the BoxPanel class. `ui` is a BoxPanel so only public BoxPanel members are visible in the outside scope.

One way to get around this is to move the declaration of `table` outside of the BoxPanel so that it's a field of SunsetTable. Then you can say

```
SunsetTable.table.update(0,0,"ABC")
```

You could also keep your code as it is and say

```
SunsetTable.ui.contents(0).asInstanceOf[ScrollPane].contents(0)
 .asInstanceOf[Table].update(0,0,"ABC")
```

Finally, you could either declare a new class that extends BoxPanel and includes an `updateTable` method, and make `ui` and instance of that, or make an `Updatable` trait that you can use in the ui delclaration, making your `ui` type `BoxPanel with Updatable`, so you can access the updateTable method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Scala, but I know you can't `sleep()` on the event dispatch thread. You need the Scala equivalent of a [continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) to do the update.

```
class Counter {
    for (i <- 1 to 10) {
        // begin Java
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // update SunsetTable with i
            }
        });
        // end Java
        Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
}
```